# Help make sense of conflicting info for tests on nonprobability samples

Tags: nonparametric

1. Which tests can and cannot be run on a nonprobability sample? (Collected by convenience and snowball sampling - not by me.) Finding a hard no to t-tests and ANOVA across the board. Then finding both yes and no, depending on the website, to chi-squares, correlations, regressions, Mann Whitney, Kruskal Wallis, Wilcoxon signed test, etc. Which is it?
2. Also, what tests can be run just to check for relationships within the sample itself, without making inferences to a population? Can chi squares, correlations, regressions, Mann-Whitney be run just to see the relationship within the sample, without the need to generalize to the population or is it pointless? Thank you.